# How to re-send invitations to shared Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

How can I resend invitations to a shared Google calendar?

I've setup a new calendar for a non-profit organization using Google Apps for Domains. I said "no" to the initial question to send out invites because I wasn't finished tweaking it and didn't want the notice to go out until it was ready.

Now that I've finished setting up the calendar (I added a year's worth of funding deadlines, meeting dates and other important dates) I want to send out the invitations, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

The calendar is not public.

Note: This is about invites to the calendar itself, not to shared events within a calendar.

Comment: when you click on the arrow on the right of the calendar name in `Your Calendars` and click `Share Calendar`. What doesn't work?

Comment: @JMax, When looking at the "Share this Calendar" page there is no link or control (that I can see) to "send invitations". I can add and remove email addresses without difficulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*To share an event*

You should be able to change this when you click to edit the event.

(I'm looking @ this now as I'm telling you)

Click the event you want to get to the edit page.
To the right middle of the screen you can add guests and give those guest privileges. After you've enter the email(s) of the guest(s) you want to add, click add.
Down at the bottom of the page is privacy settings. If you need to make the event public naturally you should know what to do.

If you click the link "Publish this event" it'll create a link you can share with others.

---

*To share the entire calendar*

If you are trying to share the entire calendar, on the main calendar page click the arrow next to the calendar and select "Share this Calendar". Follow the instructions and you should be good to go.

This link leads you to a search (through google calendar help) of sharing topics. If it doesn't help you can always search again in the search box.

Source: http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=36598

Hope this answers your question.

---

How about this?

> 1. Remove the person's email address (or multiple email addresses) that you want to resend it to by clicking on the trash can to the
>      right of their email in the "Share This Calendar" tab.
> 2. *Now click save at the bottom of that screen* It will take you back to your home calendar screen and now all you have to do is go back in
>      to the "Share This Calendar" tab and re-add those email addresses.
> 3. *Click Save Again* and now it will resend the invite to only the names you just re-added.

Source: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=229aaddb510b693b&hl=en

---

Another thought

Have you tried sharing the calendar ID? It's in the specific calendar's settings. It's another way to share the calendar.

---

(This is in comments but I'll add it here to make it easier for everyone else.)

I've found this. Not sure if you've been through it and I'm not quite entirely sure how to answer the questions so I'll pass it off to you. http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144119 . And I found this http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=143754. If you read the section about sharing with specific people outside your domain, it gives what you **can't** give them permission to do. Like see private events.

You're going to need those "outside" people signed up for account inside your domain for this to work. It's the only way.

Comment: Sorry Tremaine, but this doesn't help. The calendar is already shared. To reproduce: Create a calender, share it, add an email or two, *don't* send invitations, save, go back to calendar share settings, add and remove email addresses. This second time there is no prompt to send invitations, at least there isn't for me.

Comment: Added a new answer under edit. Let me know.

Comment: That doesn't work either unfortunately. Though it does add a a new behaviour: if the newly added address doesn't have a google account associated with it I get a prompt asking to invite them to use Google Calendar (GC generally, not this calendar specifically). If the recently re-added address does have a google account nothing happens.

Comment: I'll look again.

Comment: Can I ask, are your trying to share with specific people or your entire domain? As for the prompt, I understand that happens with GTalk and their other stuff as well. They are coming on strong. Google is trying to take over the world. You should know this by now. ;-D

Comment: And is everyone you are trying to share with inside or outside the domain or a little of both? Sorry for all the questios just trying to help you troubleshoot. (Sorry, can't wait 5 mins)

Comment: I'm sharing with both inside and outside the domain. I've not noticed any difference between the two, other than outside addy's get a prompt asking if I'm sure I want to share outside the domain. I'll do so more testing to see if there's a difference (yesterday's tests were to external addresses).

Comment: Not sure if you saw I added this. Have you tried sharing the Calendar's ID?

Comment: I've found this. Not sure if you've been through it and I'm not quite entirely sure how to answer the questions so I'll pass it off to you. [link](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144119) . And I found this [link](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=143754). If you read the section about sharing with specific people outside your domain, it gives what you **can't** give them permission to do. Like see private events.

Comment: re "share Calendar ID": I don't know what this is/means. Re: non-domain and private events: this might be where things are getting messed up. I can't quite wrap my head around their statement that non-domain users can't see private events. The calendar I'm using is private, yet after sending the iCal link to my work computer, which is not among the shared people, I can see all events and details. There is some wording around differences between the primary calendar and extra calendars which leave me with questions. This may be part of the problem, the calendar I'm using is the primary one.

Comment: The calendar ID is in the specific calendar's settings. It's another way to share the calendar. But as I just read the calendar has to be public, can't be private. As for outside domain users it actually makes sense. It's about security. You can't ask Google just because it's Google to make such exceptions. Works the same way in any other domain. You're going to need to get those other outside people you are trying to give access to, to sign up for a google account to be inside your domain.

Comment: last week just for kicks I tried removing the invitee emails, saving, and then adding them again. This time it offered to resend invitations.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem.  I have share entire calendars throughout my company, and should someone accidentally delete the calendar ,or decline adding it to their calendar, you get stuck with the other parties(other employees in my case) not being able to access the calendar, or let alone it show up as a displayable calendar on their end, even if you your end "Settings and Sharing" is has them listed as being giving access.  By shear dumb luck I found the work around.

On each of the people you have share your calendar with, set them to "See only Free/Busy(Hide Details)".

Next, refresh your browser.

Then, set them all back to whichever shared settings you originally had them at, for me it was "Make changes and Manage Sharing".

The final step is on the recipients end, they will get another email with an invite to the calendar, and this time they have to make sure they "Add" it to their calendar.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was remove all my guest saved and closed. Then I clicked edit event and added all my guest back in and it asked if I wanted to send invite and this time I clicked send.

Comment: The q is about sending invitations for the calendar itself, not a particular event.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the description slightly.  When you click "Save" you the message "Would you like to send updates to existing guests?"  Of course, this goes to all guests, not to just those that haven't responded.

Comment: The q is about sending invitations for the calendar itself, not a particular event.